# How to overwrite a git repository(including all branches) to another git repository

Tags: git, github

I have two git repos: **orginal**(with master and some feature branches) and **new**(having just the master branch as it is created new). I want to copy everything from **original** (all the branches and history) to **new**.

I have followed [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/moving-git-repository-new-server/) resource and so far am able to copy all the branches except the master branch to the **new** repo.

Here is what I have tried from **original** repo:

1. Created local copies of branches:

   ```
   git branch -a
      * master
      remotes/origin/feature1
      remotes/origin/feature2
      remotes/origin/master

   git checkout -b feature1 origin/feature1
   git checkout -b feature2 origin/feature2
   ```
2. Added a new remote(new-origin):

   ```
   git remote add new-origin <url-of-new-repo>
   ```
3. Pushing all the branches to new remote:

   ```
   git push --all new-origin
   ```

This has correctly created two feature branches on **new** repo, but didn't overwrite the master. This could happen since master exists for both the repos. Is there a way to overwrite the master branch from another repository?

Comment: In the `git branch -a` output, I do not see a `origin/master`. Where is it?

Comment: @j6t, edited now. `origin/master` is there.

Comment: Now that you have `origin/master` use the command in my answer to set the local master to that commit. After that you can `git push`, probably with `--force` to overwrite the master branch on the new repo.

Comment: @SebDieBIn, Thanks. It worked with force push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) command. Run this on the new repo after you fetched all branches from the original:

```
git branch --force master origin/master
```

This forces the local master branch to point to the same commit as the remote master branch.

Comment: the problem is that I'm not able to fetch all the branches from the original. Master branch is not copied. I have edited the question with the steps that I have taken so far.

Comment: @Deepak147 What do you with "master branch is not copied". In the edited output, there is a `origin/master` entry. It does look like it was copied, and the solution given in this answer should reset the local master branch to that of the origin.

Comment: @j6t, Thanks. It worked.